# How to create custom elements styled like material design?

Tags: qt, button, checkbox, pyqt, customization

I love material design. I love jquery, web forms and elements. It have many styles. But when i use PyQt i have default button and checkbox...

I love something like this:
[image]

Can I change qt elements so that they become similar to the elements of web-forms?
Tell me what to read or may have examples of how to do this already? I just do not know if this is possible because I do not know in which direction to look for ...

i use qt4 and windows... and know only python, not C/C++

Comment: For Qt, there is [QML](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqml.html). Most of the documentation is written for C++, but as with the rest of Qt, you don't need to know C++ in order to make good use of it. There are probably PyQt/PySide tutorials out there as well if you do a little searching, but QML is quite new technology, so don't expect too much. There's aslo [QSS](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) for styling normal Qt widgets.

Comment: QML is standalone software. But i whant use QML element as qwidget in qdialog window. is posible?

Comment: Please read the Qt Documentation for QML: e.g. [Integrating QML Code with Existing Qt UI Code](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html).

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, but it would be quite some work. It's probably not supported natively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start creating your own widgets and override the paintEvent

I am putting in an example here that mostly summarizes what you need to know. 
The example shows the checkbox as an on/off button.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
#===============================================================================
# MyCheckBox
#===============================================================================
#className
class MyCheckBox(QtGui.QCheckBox):
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# class Variables
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
    #no classVariables

#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
# Constructor  
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            QtGui.QCheckBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n" + 
                      "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n")
            #set default check as True 
            self.setChecked(True)
            #set default enable as True
            #    if it set to false will always remain on/off
            #    here it is on as setChecked is True
            self.setEnabled(True)
            self._enable = True
#|--------------------------End of Constructor---------------------------------| 
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
#   mousePressEvent
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    #overrite 
    def mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
            #tick on and off set here
            if self.isChecked():
                self.setChecked(False)
            else:
                self.setChecked(True)
            return QtGui.QCheckBox.mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
#|--------------------------End of mousePressEvent-----------------------------| 

#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
# paintEvent
#|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    def paintEvent(self,event):

            #just setting some size aspects
            self.setMinimumHeight(40)
            self.setMinimumWidth(100)
            self.setMaximumHeight(50)
            self.setMaximumWidth(150)

            self.resize(self.parent().width(),self.parent().height())
            painter = QtGui.QPainter()
            painter.begin(self)

            #for the black background
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0),style=QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
            painter.fillRect(self.rect(),brush)


            #smooth curves
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

            #for the on off font
            font  = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Courier New")
            font.setPixelSize(28)
            painter.setFont(font)        

            #change the look for on/off
            if self.isChecked():
                #blue fill
                brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(50,50,255),style=QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
                painter.setBrush(brush)

                #rounded rectangle as a whole
                painter.drawRoundedRect(0,0,self.width()-2,self.height()-2, \
                                   self.height()/2,self.height()/2)

                #white circle/button instead of the tick mark
                brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255),style=QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
                painter.setBrush(brush)
                painter.drawEllipse(self.width()-self.height(),0,self.height(),self.height())

                #on text
                painter.drawText(self.width()/4,self.height()/1.5, "On")

            else:
                #gray fill
                brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(50,50,50),style=QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
                painter.setBrush(brush)

                #rounded rectangle as a whole
                painter.drawRoundedRect(0,0,self.width()-2,self.height()-2, \
                                   self.height()/2,self.height()/2)

                #white circle/button instead of the tick but in different location
                brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255),style=QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
                painter.setBrush(brush)
                painter.drawEllipse(0,0,self.height(),self.height())

                #off text
                painter.drawText(self.width()/2,self.height()/1.5, "Off")


#|-----------------------End of paintEvent-------------------------------------|
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wgt = QtGui.QWidget()
    wgt.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n")
    cb = MyCheckBox()
    cb.setParent(wgt)
    layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(cb)
    wgt.resize(200,100)
    wgt.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## EDIT:

Attaching screen-shots for how it looks

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks. its worked! )
but generate a error: line 38, in mousePressEvent
return QtGui.QCheckBox.mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: QCheckBox.mousePressEvent() is a private method

Comment: Nothing like private in python. I am not sure what error are you pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

Custom style can be added much more easily.
For example:

```
slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
slider.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid #999999;height: 8px;)
```

More Examples can be found [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: But can you achieve exactly the design that the asker indicated in his screenshots?

Comment: Yes you can achieve them.

Comment: I doubt it. qt stylesheets are not almighty.

Comment: @Trilarion Agree. Qt Stylesheets cannot handle animations. I think the easiest way to do this is using elements created in QML.